# Submit button not saving/updating changes Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this form:

```
   <fieldset data-model="idea-art" class="idea-edit">
  <h2>Artwork Specs</h2>

 <%= form_for @idea do |f| %>
 <div data-attribute="art_status" class="edit-field">
 <%= f.label :art_status, "Art Status" %>
 <%= f.select :art_status, Idea::ART_STATUSES %>
</div>
<div data-attribute="artist" class="edit-field">
<%= f.label :artist_id, "Artist" %>
<%= f.select :artist_id, User.artists.collect{|x|[x.full_name, x.id]}, :include_blank => 
true %>
</div>
<div data-attribute="default_size" class="edit-field">
<%= f.label :default_artwork_id, "Default Artwork" %>
<%= f.select :default_artwork_id, @idea.artworks.collect{|x|[x.dimensions, x.id]}, 
:include_blank => true %>
</div>
<div data-attribute="colors_offered" class="edit-field">
<%= f.label :colors, 'Colors Offered' %>
<%= f.collection_select :color_ids,  Color.master_colors.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, 
{multiple: true}%>
</div>
<div data-attribute="base" class="edit-field">
<%= f.label :base, "Base" %>
<%= f.check_box :base %>
</div>
<div data-attribute="special_instructions" class="edit-field">
<%= f.label :special_instructions, "Special Instructions" %>
<%= f.text_area :special_instructions %>
</div>

<div data-attribute="artwork" class="edit-field">
  <%= f.fields_for :artworks do |artworks_f| %>
      <%= render 'artwork_fields', f: artworks_f %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= link_to_add_fields "Click To Add Artwork", f, :artworks %>
  </p>

</div>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <%end%>
</fieldset>
```

when I click submit my changes are not updated. I have tried many things and nothing seems to work. I am new to ruby and have read the RailsGuide to form helpers and I still can't quite figure it out.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the request in Rails server log? If so, look for a Rollback in the log, which might indicate that ur models are invalid, perhaps due to strong parameters settings. If the request is not making it to the server, inspect for javascript errors on the page, then make sure you're not using (or intend to use) ajax requests, in which case you might need to require jquery_ujs in application.js along with csrf_meta_tag in you layout.

Comment: to add to this, another simple way if you do not want to dig through log files, is to add a bang at the endof your save in the controller action that is processing the form.  for instance if you have a save or update_attributes call use .save! or .update_attributes! instead to raise the ererors